# Rails - Combing conditions with OR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, where-clause

I am implementing filter logics in ruby on rails, where the user can filter the records combined with the **OR operator**. So I checked the way of implementing OR in **active record** and since we are in rails 5, we have [or method](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-or) to combine conditions.

When using the OR method, I get the query in like the below,

```
SELECT "users".*
FROM "users"
WHERE (
              (
                      (
                              "users"."first_name" ILIKE '%name1%' OR "users"."last_name" ILIKE '%name2%'
                          )
                      OR
                      "users"."email" ILIKE '%email%'
                  )
              OR (
                  "users"."email" ILIKE '%email%'
                  )
          );
```

The query build is like, `Model.where((((A OR B) OR C) OR D))`. We are using Postgres as a database.

The doubt I had is `(((A OR B) OR C) OR D)` and `(A OR B OR C OR D)` equal in Postgres? and is there any performance differences between these two.

NOTE: I checked the query constructed by [Ransack advanced search](http://ransack-demo.herokuapp.com/users/advanced_search), the query constructed in `(((A OR B) OR C) OR D)` format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is `(((A OR B) OR C) OR D)` and `(A OR B OR C OR D)` equal in Postgres?

Is not about Postgres, but about logical operators in general. Yes, both expression are equivalent (although the first one is unnecessary complex):

- if any of the 4 conditions is true, both logical expressions produce a true result
- if all 4 conditions are false, both expressions produce a false result